# Visual Studio Code: Xcode verifying environment is always running and never stops

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-code

The process Xcode verifying environment is always running in VS Code and never stops:

[image: Xcode verifying environment]

I use Visual Studio Code Version 1.87.0 (Universal) and Xcode Version 15.2 on my iMac.

Why is Xcode verifying environment always running? I think this issue came after a VS Code update.